# Можно ли задать alpha по координатам?

Tags: android

Нужно скрыть layout частично, типо setApha = 0 from y to y

Comment: Если заранее известно какая часть должна будет быть скрыта, можно изначально использовать несколько полей. Второй вариант поиграться с градиентом, может получиться и третий точно рабочий, это использовать маску. То есть на канвасе нарисовать какой-то объект (часть которая должна быть скрыта) и залить её прозрачным цветом

Comment: Заранее не известно . y  координаты будут меняться в зависимости от скроллинга

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите создать плавного появления из прозрачности во время скролла, то я бы предложил не делать ваш скролл полупрозрачным, а поверх него накладывать полупрозрачную вью с цветом бэкграунда. Выглядеть будет так же.

Делаем `FrameLayout`, в нем 3 объекта. Первым идет обязательно ваш `ScrollView`. Затем две простые `View`, обе во всю ширину парента, одну прилепляем к верхней стороне, вторую к нижней. Допустим у `ScrollView` белый бэкграунд. Тогда делаем вот такой drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:startColor="#00FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Он даст вам плавный переход от белого к прозрачному от верхней грани до нижней. Теперь ставим этот drawble как бэкграунд нашим двум `View` во `FrameLayout`, и одной из них выставляем `android:rotation="180"`. Они дадут вам плавное пропадание сверху и снизу.

Если у вас бэкграунд не монотонный, то придется создать свой `View`, где в onDraw вы получаете кусок бэкграунда из родителя и на него уже деалете градиент. Чуть сложнее, но вполне реально